Как мне сделать так, чтобы кнопки располагались влево, в центре и вправо?
Всем привет! У меня такой вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка "Предыдущая страница" располагалась в левой стороне, счётчик страницы посередине и кнопка "Следующая страница" в правой стороне? При этом, расстояние от кнопки "Предыдущая страница" до индикатора страницы должно быть таким же, как и от кнопки "Следующая страница" до индикатора страницы. Много раз пытался через button, через justify-content, через left, right, но не помогло это как-то. Вроде сделал навигацию удобную, но во всех трёх страницах у меня три кнопки неравномерно распределены относительно горизонтали.
Образец, как расстояние от кнопки "Предыдущая страница" до индикатора страницы должно быть таким же, как и от кнопки "Следующая страница" до индикатора страницы:

У меня получилось как-то не по образцу:

Код CSS:
.navbar {
    background-color: #FEFFA8;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.navbar a {
    display: inline;
}

.previous {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 14%;
}

.previous_hidden {
    background-color: #FEFFA8;
    color: #FEFFA8;
    border: 1px #FEFFA8;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 14%;
}

.counter {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.next {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.next_hidden {
    background-color: #FEFFA8;
    color: #FEFFA8;
    border: 1px #FEFFA8;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

Код первой страницы:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>1.2. Политика безопасности</title>
    <style>
        span.bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a class="previous_hidden">Предыдущая страница</a>
            <a class="counter">1</a> из 3
            <a href="index6_2.html" class="next">Следующая страница</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <h1 align = "center">1.2. Политика безопасности</h1>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;С практической точки зрения политику безопасности целесообразно рассматривать на трех уровнях детализации. К верхнему уровню можно отнести решения, затрагивающие организацию в целом. Они носят весьма общий характер и, как правило, исходят от руководства организации. Примерный список подобных решений может включать в себя следующие элементы:</p>
    <p>- решение сформировать или пересмотреть комплексную программу обеспечения информационной безопасности, назначение ответственных за продвижение программы;</p>
    <p>- формулировка целей, которые преследует организация в области информационной безопасности, определение общих направлений в достижении этих целей;</p>
    <p>- обеспечение базы для соблюдения законов и правил;</p>
    <p>- формулировка административных решений по тем вопросам реализации программы безопасности, которые должны рассматриваться на уровне организации в целом.</p>
</body>
</html>

Код второй страницы:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>1.3. Программа безопасности</title>
    <style>
        span.bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="index6_1.html" class="previous">Предыдущая страница</a>
            <a class="counter">2</a> из 3
            <a href="index6_3.html" class="next">Следующая страница</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <h1 align = "center">1.3. Программа безопасности</h1>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;После того, как сформулирована политика безопасности, можно приступать к составлению программы ее реализации и собственно к реализации.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Чтобы понять и реализовать какую-либо программу, ее нужно структурировать по уровням, обычно в соответствии со структурой организации. В простейшем и самом распространенном случае достаточно двух уровней - верхнего, или центрального, который охватывает всю организацию, и нижнего, или служебного, который относится к отдельным услугам или группам однородных сервисов.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Программу верхнего уровня возглавляет лицо, отвечающее за информационную безопасность организации. У этой программы следующие главные цели:</p>
    <p>- управление рисками (оценка рисков, выбор эффективных средств защиты);</p>
    <p>- координация деятельности в области информационной безопасности, пополнение и распределение ресурсов;</p>
    <p>- стратегическое планирование;</p>
    <p>- контроль деятельности в области информационной безопасности.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;В рамках программы верхнего уровня принимаются стратегические решения по обеспечению безопасности, оцениваются технологические новинки. Информационные технологии развиваются очень быстро, и необходимо иметь четкую политику отслеживания и внедрения новых средств.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Контроль деятельности в области безопасности имеет двустороннюю направленность. Во-первых, необходимо гарантировать, что действия организации не противоречат законам. При этом следует поддерживать контакты с внешними контролирующими организациями. Во-вторых, нужно постоянно отслеживать состояние безопасности внутри организации, реагировать на случаи нарушений и дорабатывать защитные меры с учетом изменения обстановки.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Следует подчеркнуть, что программа верхнего уровня должна занимать строго определенное место в деятельности организации, она должна официально приниматься и поддерживаться руководством, а также иметь определенный штат и бюджет.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Цель программы нижнего уровня - обеспечить надежную и экономичную защиту конкретного сервиса или группы однородных сервисов. На этом уровне решается, какие следует использовать механизмы защиты; закупаются и устанавливаются технические средства; выполняется повседневное администрирование; отслеживается состояние слабых мест и т.п. Обычно за программу нижнего уровня отвечают администраторы сервисов.</p>
</body>
</html>

Код третьей страницы:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>1.4. Синхронизация программы безопасности с жизненным циклом систем</title>
    <style>
        span.bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="index6_2.html" class="previous">Предыдущая страница</a>
            <a class="counter">3</a> из 3
            <a class="next_hidden">Следующая страница</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <h1 align = "center">1.4. Синхронизация программы безопасности с жизненным циклом систем</h1>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Если синхронизировать программу безопасности нижнего уровня с жизненным циклом защищаемого сервиса, можно добиться большего эффекта с меньшими затратами. Программисты знают, что добавить новую возможность к уже готовой системе на порядок сложнее, чем изначально спроектировать и реализовать ее. То же справедливо и для информационной безопасности.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;В жизненном цикле информационного сервиса можно выделить следующие этапы:</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span class = "bold">Инициация.</span> Сервис устанавливается, конфигурируется, тестируется и вводится в эксплуатацию.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span class = "bold">Закупка.</span> На данном этапе составляются спецификации, прорабатываются варианты приобретения, выполняется собственно закупка.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span class = "bold">Установка.</span> Сервис устанавливается, конфигурируется, тестируется и вводится в эксплуатацию.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span class = "bold">Эксплуатация.</span> На данном этапе сервис не только работает и администрируется, но и подвергается модификациям.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span class = "bold">Выведение из эксплуатации.</span> Происходит переход на новый сервис.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Рассмотрим действия, выполняемые на каждом из этапов, более подробно.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;На этапе инициации оформляется понимание того, что необходимо приобрести новый или значительно модернизировать существующий сервис; определяется, какими характеристиками и какой функциональностью он должен обладать; оцениваются финансовые и иные ограничения.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;С точки зрения безопасности важнейшим действием здесь является оценка критичности как самого сервиса, так и информации, которая с его помощью будет обрабатываться. Требуется сформулировать ответы на следующие вопросы:</p>
    <p>- какого рода информация предназначается для обслуживания новым сервисом?</p>
    <p>- каковы возможные последствия нарушения конфиденциальности, целостности и доступности этой информации?</p>
    <p>- каковы угрозы, по отношению к которым сервис и информация будут наиболее уязвимы?</p>
    <p>- есть ли какие-либо особенности нового сервиса (например, территориальная распределенность компонентов), требующие принятия специальных процедурных мер?</p>
    <p>- каковы характеристики персонала, имеющие отношение к безопасности (квалификация, благонадежность)?</p>
    <p>- каковы законодательные положения и внутренние правила, которым должен соответствовать новый сервис?</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Результаты оценки критичности являются отправной точкой в составлении спецификаций. Кроме того, они определяют ту меру внимания, которую служба безопасности организации должна уделять новому сервису на последующих этапах его жизненного цикла.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Этап закупки - один из самых сложных. Нужно окончательно сформулировать требования к защитным средствам нового сервиса, к компании, которая может претендовать на роль поставщика, и к квалификации, которой должен обладать персонал, использующий или обслуживающий закупаемый продукт. Все эти сведения оформляются в виде спецификации, куда входят не только аппаратура и программы, но и документация, обслуживание, обучение персонала. Разумеется, особое внимание должно уделяться вопросам совместимости нового сервиса с существующей конфигурацией. Подчеркнем также, что нередко средства безопасности являются необязательными компонентами коммерческих продуктов, и нужно проследить, чтобы соответствующие пункты не выпали из спецификации.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Когда продукт закуплен, его необходимо установить. Несмотря на кажущуюся простоту, установка является очень ответственным делом. Во-первых, новый продукт следует сконфигурировать. Как правило, коммерческие продукты поставляются с отключенными средствами безопасности; их необходимо включить и должным образом настроить. Для большой организации, где много пользователей и данных, начальная настройка может стать весьма трудоемким и ответственным делом.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Во-вторых, новый сервис нуждается в процедурных регуляторах. Следует позаботиться о чистоте и охране помещения, о документах, регламентирующих использование сервиса, о подготовке планов на случай экстренных ситуаций, об организации обучения пользователей и т.п.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;После принятия перечисленных мер необходимо провести тестирование. Его полнота и комплексность могут служить гарантией безопасности эксплуатации в штатном режиме.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Период эксплуатации - самый длительный и сложный. С психологической точки зрения наибольшую опасность в это время представляют незначительные изменения в конфигурации сервиса, в поведении пользователей и администраторов. Если безопасность не поддерживать, она ослабевает. Пользователи не столь ревностно выполняют должностные инструкции, администраторы менее тщательно анализируют регистрационную информацию. То один, то другой пользователь получает дополнительные привилегии. Кажется, что в сущности ничего не изменилось; на самом же деле от былой безопасности не осталось и следа.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Для борьбы с эффектом медленных изменений приходится прибегать к периодическим проверкам безопасности сервиса. Разумеется, после значительных модификаций подобные проверки являются обязательными.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;При выведении из эксплуатации затрагиваются аппаратно-программные компоненты сервиса и обрабатываемые им данные. Аппаратура продается, утилизируется или выбрасывается. Только в специфических случаях необходимо заботиться о физическом разрушении аппаратных компонентов, хранящих конфиденциальную информацию. Программы, вероятно, просто стираются, если иное не предусмотрено лицензионным соглашением.</p>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;При выведении данных из эксплуатации их обычно переносят на другую систему, архивируют, выбрасывают или уничтожают. Если архивирование производится с намерением впоследствии прочитать данные в другом месте, следует позаботиться об аппаратно-программной совместимости средств чтения и записи. Информационные технологии развиваются очень быстро, и через несколько лет устройств, способных прочитать старый носитель, может просто не оказаться. Если данные архивируются в зашифрованном виде, необходимо сохранить ключ и средства расшифровки. При архивировании и хранении архивной информации нельзя забывать о поддержании конфиденциальности данных.</p>
</body>
</html>


вопрос решить можно flex`ом и обернуть ваши ссылочки в div, и убрать margin у ссылок


.navbar {
    background-color: #FEFFA8;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;/*Добавлено*/
    flex-direction: row;/*Добавлено*/
    justify-content: space-around;/*Добавлено*/
    align-items: center;/*Добавлено*/
}

.navbar a {
    display: inline;
}

.previous {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*margin-left: 14%;*/
}

.previous_hidden {
    background-color: #FEFFA8;
    color: #FEFFA8;
    border: 1px #FEFFA8;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*margin-left: 14%;*/
}

.counter {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*margin-left: 25%;*/
}

.next {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*margin-left: 25%;*/
}

.next_hidden {
    background-color: #FEFFA8;
    color: #FEFFA8;
    border: 1px #FEFFA8;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*margin-left: 25%;*/
}
 <header>
      <div class="navbar">
          <div>
          <a class="previous">Предыдущая страница</a>
          </div>
          <div>
          <a class="counter">3</a> из 3
          </div>
          <div>
          <a href="index6_2.html" class="next_hidden">Следующая страница</a>
          </div>
        </div>
  </header>
  <h1 align = "center">1.2. Политика безопасности</h1>
  <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;С практической точки зрения политику безопасности целесообразно рассматривать на трех уровнях детализации. К верхнему уровню можно отнести решения, затрагивающие организацию в целом. Они носят весьма общий характер и, как правило, исходят от руководства организации. Примерный список подобных решений может включать в себя следующие элементы:</p>
  <p>- решение сформировать или пересмотреть комплексную программу обеспечения информационной безопасности, назначение ответственных за продвижение программы;</p>
  <p>- формулировка целей, которые преследует организация в области информационной безопасности, определение общих направлений в достижении этих целей;</p>
  <p>- обеспечение базы для соблюдения законов и правил;</p>
  <p>- формулировка административных решений по тем вопросам реализации программы безопасности, которые должны рассматриваться на уровне организации в целом.</p>





Спасибо! Действительно помогло, теперь работает.
